# How to get the fully qualified mailbox server name in exchange server?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

The best choice for me in this case is using powershell script, but other suggestions are welcome.

Get-MailboxServer can get the server name, but it is not the fully qualified name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to convert a NETBIOS name to the FQDN, this'll do the trick:

```
$o = Get-MailboxServer
([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($o)).HostName
```

Comment: I don't have an Exchange Server to be able to verify what the Get-MailboxServer returns, but we can adjust the answer based the exact details.

Answer (score 1):

fqdn is an attribute returned with the `get-exchangeserver` cmdlet.

Try `(get-exchangeserver MYEXCHANGESERVER).fqdn`

Or just run `get-exchangeserver | select fqdn` to view the fully qualified names for all servers in your environment.